# import seaborn displays error: Import "seaborn" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, seaborn, python-import

I am new prgrammer, using VScode and Ubuntu for python. I have installed seaborn from Ubuntu by "pip install seabron". But when I am running from VSCode yellow marked warning displays "Import "seaborn" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)". Using python 3.8.10, Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
How may I solve this?

I installed the seaborn by the following commad:
pip install seaborn.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to python version mismatch

**You need to make sure that the python interpreter version from terminal version is the same with your python version selection in VSCode.**

1. Open terminal in your computer and type `python3`, you will see your python version.
2. Open VSCode and then open any folder related to python project, check your python version at the bottom right on IDE VSCode
3. Finally change the python version to make it same with your computer python version and save.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose your python interpreter which you installed the package in.